# C-like procedures in C++?

Tags: c++, c, oop

Does the `C++` **correct** programming style demand writing all your code with classes or are `C`-like procedures allowed ? If I were to give some code to someone else, would it be accepted as `C++` just because it has `std::vector` and `std::string` (instead of `char *`) inside, or **everything** has to be a class?

eg:

```
int number = 204;
std::string result = my_procedure(number);

OR

MyClass machine;
std::string result = machine.get(number);
```

Are there cases where the programmer, will have to, or is allowed to have `C`-like procedures in some of his source code ? Did you ever had to do something like that?

In the context of this question where does the margin between `C` and `C++` exist (if any)?

I hope my question is clear and inline with the rules.

Comment: C++ offers more than just objects. A lot of C++ code has been written that does not use any classes at all.

Comment: 200-300 lines of code just for int-to-string conversion?

Comment: Note that the question isn't asking whether this is **valid** C++, it's asking if it's **good practice**. Merely making the observation that there's lots of C++ code written this way doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @myrkos, I do not remember the exact length. The code is in a computer 25 minutes away.

Comment: @Muggen, I mean 200-300 lines of code for such a simple task are a little too much. You should look at a tutorial.

Comment: @myrkos, yeah I guess it was less than that then.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa

Comment: @myrkos, ah not `itoa`. input : `142` will return the string `A Hundred and fourty two`. You see what I mean ? Something like integer to words.

Comment: Oh, I see. That would make it longer. Lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ is a multi-paradigm language, where OO, procedural, generic/generative and - to a lesser (but increasing with C++0x) extent functional - are among the paradigms.  You should use whichever is the best fit for the problem: you want the code to be easy to get and keep right, and hard to stuff up.

The utility of classes is in packaging data (state) along with the related functions.  If your `wordify` function doesn't need to retain any state between calls, then there's no need to use a class/object.  That said, if you can predict that you will soon want to have state, then it may be useful to start with a class so that the client code doesn't need to change as much.

For example, imagine adding a parameter to the function to specify whether the output should be "first", "second" instead of "one", "two".  You want the behaviour to be set once and remembered, but somewhere else in the application some other code may also use the functionality but prefer the other setting.  It's a good idea to use an object to hold the state and arrange it so each object's lifetime and accessibility aligns with the code that will use it.

EDIT:

> In the context of this question where does the margin between C and C++ exist (if any)?

C++ just gives you a richer set of ways to tackle your programming tasks, each with their necessary pros and cons.  There are plenty of times when the best way is still the same way it would have been done in C.  It would be perverse for a C++ programmer to choose a worse way simply because it was only possible in C++.  Still, such choices exist at myriad levels, so it's common to have say a non-[class-]member function that takes a `const std::string&` parameter, combining the procedural function call with object-oriented data that's been generated by a `template`: it all works well together.

Comment: Nice examples on the last two paragraphs.

Answer (score 10):

It's certainly OK to have free functions in your code -- this is a matter of architecture, not of "++ness". For small programs it doesn't even make sense to go all-in with classes, as OO is really a tool to manage complexity. If the complexity isn't there to begin with, why bother?

Your second question, where is the line drawn, doesn't have a short answer. The obvious one is that the line is drawn in all places where the C standard differs from the one for C++. But if you are looking for a list of high-level language features that C++ has and C does not, here are some of them:

- Class types and OO (of course)
- The STL
- Function/operator overloading
- References
- Templates
- `new`/`delete` to manage memory

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows a variety of programming styles, procedural code being one of them.

Which style to use depends on the problem you are trying to solve. The margin between C and C++ is are you compiling your code with a C++ compiler.

I do at times use procedural functions in my code. Sometimes it best solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

C++ code can still be valid C++ code even without classes. Classes are more of a feature, and are not required in every piece of code.

C++ is basically C with more features, so there isn't really a "margin" between the two languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you read Stroustrup's Design and Evolution, you'll see that C++ was intended to support multiple programming styles. Use whichever one is most appropriate the problem (not the same as always just usnig the one you know.)

In legacy real world applications, there is often very little distinction. Some C++ code was originally C code nad then recompilied. Slowly it migrates to use C++ features to improve its quality.

In short, Yes, C++ code can be procedural. But you'll find it does differ from C code if you use C++ features where appropriate.

What is good practice needs to consider things like encapsulation, testability, and the comprehensibility of the client API.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string wordify(int n)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << n;     // put the integer into the stream
   return ss.str(); // return the string
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = wordify(42);
    string s2 = wordify(45678);
    string s3 = wordify(-99);

    cout << s1 << ' ' << s2 << ' ' << s3 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That is not really what I was talking about. Also, I was not trying to implement `itoa()` but `integer-to-words`. eg. `142` --> `a Hundred and fourty two`. **not** `142` --> `"142"`. I was using this code snippet as an example. Also, welcome to SO. Next time try to format your code with the `{}` button.